# How do I get the ID of a parent element as the title of an event?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a long list of feature toggles. Each is a react component. I've added an id to each toggle, `button id='ga-enable-${feature.name}`.

The idea behind this was so that I could create distinct events for each one in Google Tag Manger by having an event name `Feature: {{Click ID}}`.

However, for inexplicable reasons and which I have no control over, the component sometimes registers with an additional div underneath it. By this I mean:

Sometimes it is: `div.settings-group > button.ant-switch`
Other times it is: `div.settings-group > button.ant-switch > div.ant-handle-switch`

The former case is straightforward and works as planned, because the ID is attached to `button`. However, for the second instance, the Click ID is blank.

I've tried creating a custom variable using `closest()` but that doesn't seem to facilitate what I need here in retrieving the ClicK ID.

Is there a way for me to get the ID of the parent in the event name to facilitate cases where the second CSS selector trigger is required?

Comment: Can you show the trigger for capturing the click element? We might able to create a trigger only target the `button` and it would work as you expected.